# Change GID of system groups (GID 100 - 105 to 200 - 205)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, security

I have an Ubuntu server connected to a Microsoft Active Directory for Authentication with NIS/Unix extentions enabled. Every AD user therefore has an primary group ID (GID), which is 100 for IT staff up to 105 for normal users. When a user now logs into the mentioned Ubuntu server, this AD-GID is mapped to the local groups, which are system groups. Because of that I need to change the local GIDs for some system groups. This is what comes by default:

```
users:x:100:
systemd-journal:x:101:
systemd-timesync:x:102:
systemd-network:x:103:
systemd-resolve:x:104:
systemd-bus-proxy:x:105:
```

I can use the `groupmod` to modify the GID and after rebooting the system everything seems to work fine. Syslog does not show any suspicious behavior related to the changed GIDs. I used the find command to look for any folder that has rights for these groups, but I found nothing:

```
sudo find / -type d -gid 100 -not -path /data
```

Is there something I should check beside the filesystem permissions? Or is there a "right way" to change those GIDs?

Comment: See `/usr/share/doc/base-passwd/README`: "The Debian base-passwd package contains the master versions of /etc/passwd and
/etc/group. ... They comprise only "global static" ids: that is,
those which are reserved globally for the benefit of packages which need to
include files owned by those users or groups, or need the ids compiled into
binaries." I wouldn't change GIDs < 500. Things may appear to work now, and break in mysterious ways later.

Comment: Thank you for pointing to the readme. I would avoid using those GIDs that, if I could, of course. The ID/GID strategy was designed ages ago and BSD (main OS at my company) does not seem to use GIDs above 99, this is why it is not a problem on the most part of our servers.